# How to have ultragrid rows have different backcolors based on a value of a cell?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gridview, infragistics

I have an infragistics UltraGridView in my winform application and would like to have different colors assigned to different rows based on a specific cell value. For instance if a cell [Status] equals 2 the row should be colored blue, etc.

I can do this at the initialize row but **that is not enough**. Because status can be changed in the code and the color should change accordingly. What is the most effective way to achieve this? Sample code is appreciated.

The grid is bound to a `bindingSource` and the `bindingSource.dataSource` is `BindingList` of an object.

```
private void dgvProduction_InitializeRow(object sender, InitializeRowEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Row.Cells["StatusId"].Value.ToString())
        {
            case "0":
                e.Row.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                break;
            case "1":
                e.Row.Appearance.BackColor = Color.White;
                break;
            case "2":
                e.Row.Appearance.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: changing the cell value, by the user or by the code behind, will always fire InitializeRow. So your code should work. Check if you are not doing something else that prevents the row updating.

Answer (score 0):

We implement this by creating two separate methods, one called ApplyRowHighlights that iterates through each row and calls a second method named ApplySingleRowHighlight.  We then call the ApplyRowHighlights method whenever the grid is loaded (triggered by the GridLoaded event of the grid).  We also call the ApplySingleRowHighlight method for individual rows after making modifications to a given row.

The following are a few simplified sample methods of those mentioned above:

```
    Private Sub pg_GridLoaded() Handles pg.GridLoaded
        ApplyRowHighlights()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ApplyRowHighlights()

        Dim intCount As Integer = 0

        For Each oRow In pg.ugData.Rows.GetRowEnumerator(GridRowType.DataRow, Nothing, Nothing)
            If oRow.VisibleIndex > -1 Then
                ApplySingleRowHighlight(oRow, intCount)
            End If
        Next

        ' intCount used in record count method

    End Sub

    Private Sub ApplySingleRowHighlight(oRow As UltraGridRow, ByRef intCount As Integer)

        If oRow Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        oRow.Appearance.BackColor = MDI.ApSettings.NeutralHighlight

        If oRow.Cells.Exists("IsStandard") Then
            If Not IsDBNull(oRow.Cells("IsStandard").Value) Then
                If CBool(oRow.Cells("IsStandard").Value) Then
                    oRow.Appearance.BackColor = MDI.ApSettings.CalibrationStandardHighlight
                End If
            End If
        End If

        ApplyPastDueRowHighlighting(oRow, intCount, "CalibrationDue", "FrequencyGuid", "FrequencyUnits", MDI.ApSettings.PastDueHighlight, MDI.ApSettings.SoonDueHighlight)

    End Sub
```

Here is an example of a WinForm application that applies different row formatting based on the values within the UltraGrid.

[image]